# How to get Nautilus and Launcher to show drives mounted in non-standard folder

Tags: mount, nautilus

If I mount a drive in `/media` or somewhere in my home folder, it automatically shows in both Nautilus (under Devices in its side bar) and on the Launcher.

However, if I mount the drive in `${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/mnt` (that's `/run/user/1000/mnt`), neither Nautilus nor the Launcher shows it.

Is it possible to get Nautilus and the Launcher to automatically show those folders when mounted?

**More information**

It is not a single drive, but several different drives that are mounted only when needed, not permanently. Therefore, `/etc/fstab` would not be appropriate.

If there isn't a solution to this, I shall simply change the scripts to move the mount point to my home folder in `~/mnt`.

Comment: Is the drive you're mounting present in /dev ?

Comment: Oh, now I think of it (as you didn't mention *specifically* you didn't want this solution): Just put it in the fstab!  :D :D :D

Comment: @Fabby Thanks for the ideas. `fstab` is not appropriate, because they can be different drives with different names, and they are mounted only as needed, not permanently. I shall edit my answer to clarify. The mount does appear in `/dev/mapper`, although I don't know how that helps.

Comment: I'm thinking about udev...  If it gets into /dev/ it should be possible to create a udev rule...
Can you post more info?  Like what commands you actually use so I can simulate on my machine and come up with something...

Comment: @Fabby I am using TrueCrypt to mount various devices or file containers. It is done via the GUI. The name under `/dev/mapper` is always of the form `/dev/mapper/truecryptN`, where `N` is a number between 1 and 64. The number cannot be determined in advance. (If this is difficult or complex to solve, please don't worry — I'll just move the mount point to my home folder. I had hoped that it might be as simple as adding the target folder to some list of folders recognised by Nautilus, but it seems to be getting too complicated.)